# Creating Carousel using FutureBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am storing my images in Firestore Document and would like to load them using FutureBuilder. Here's what I have done so far:

```
     Future getCarouselWidget() async {
        var firestore = Firestore.instance;
        QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("carousel").getDocuments();
        return qn.documents;
      }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCarouselWidget(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return new CircularProgressIndicator(); 
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return new Text("fetch error");
              } else {
                return new Container(
                    height: 250.0,
                    child: new Carousel(
                      boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                      images: [NetworkImage(snapshot.data[0].data["img_2"])],
                      autoplay: false,
                      dotSize: 4.0,
                      indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
                      animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                    ));
              }
            }
          }),
    );
  }'
```

Using the code above, I can display an image without any errors. However, I don't know how to loop through the snapshot data to display a list of images.

Below is my firestore structure:

[image: My firestore structure]

Comment: I need this too interesting...

Comment: Having exaxtly the same issue like you. So please update this when solution is available.

Comment: @stucked_overflow, please see my updated question. I got it to display one image. I just need help on displaying a list of images.

Comment: That's the real deal...If you iterate using FutureBuilder within then it will show your previous error -> casting Future<dynamic> to ImageProvider<dynamic>

Comment: Correct. That's where I am stuck.

Comment: We stucked.....

Comment: @stucked_overflow, please see my answer below. If it helps you, then please upvote.

Comment: not sure it works on my case, i have 1 method to retrieve all the list data without images then another method just to retrieve the image 2 separate api calls. but I got your point here so seems like this plugin cannot support future it will only take the list of images so we must somehow make the loop and provide this list to the plugin

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Do you know how to insert and onpressed() function for each image in the carousel?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627148/how-to-cast-convert-futuredynamic-into-image The concept is yours but this is how actually how to convert/cast Future<dynamic> into Image so I think using Future and do loop will work too

Comment: I dont think this plugin has onpress() or onTap() or something similar to that. You might want to contact the author of the plugin and let's see how the possibility of this getting implemented. If not you might want to try this instead https://gist.github.com/collinjackson/4fddbfa2830ea3ac033e34622f278824 here you got full control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's the solution. Basically, I looped through the document snapshot and saved the result in a list. Then, I set the list to the image.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var idx = 1;
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCarouselWidget(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            List<NetworkImage> list = new List<NetworkImage>();
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return new CircularProgressIndicator(); 
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return new Text("fetch error");
              } else {

                //Create for loop and store the urls in the list 
                for(int i = 0; i < snapshot.data[0].data.length; i++ ) {
                  debugPrint("Index is " + idx.toString());
                  list.add(NetworkImage(snapshot.data[0].data["img_"+idx.toString()]));
                  idx++;
                }
                return new Container(
                    height: 250.0,
                    child: new Carousel(
                      boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                      images: list,   <== Set the list here 
                      autoplay: true,
                      dotSize: 4.0,
                      indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
                      animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                    ));
              }
            }
          }),
    );
```

Comment: thanks for the above example and it helped me to do the same for my flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this youtube guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2I0osLdjgQ
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

```
//I assume this function futures a list of images
Future getCarouselWidget() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("carousel").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }


Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getCarouselWidget(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                switch( snapshot.connectionState ){
                   case ConnectionState.none:
                      return new Text("Data is not fetched");
                   case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return new CircularProgressIndicator();
                   case ConnectionState.done:
                      if(snapshot.hasError){
                          return new Text("fetch error")
                      } else {
                         return new Container(
                          height: 250.0,
                          child: new Carousel(
                          boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                          images: snapshot.data,
                          autoplay: false,
                          dotSize: 4.0,
                          indicatorBgPadding: 4.0,
                          animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                        ));
                      }
                   default:
                      return Text("connection is just active");
                }
            }
```

Edit: I do not have any docs on the datatype of the firestore documentation.
I do not know if below code is correct.

```
Future getCarouselWidget() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("carousel").getDocuments();
    // convert DocumentSnapshots to Images.
    // I am assuming Document Snapshots are <String, Images>
    var ret = new List();
    qn.documents.forEach( 
       (v) => 
           for( var e in v.data.values ) {
               ret.add(new NetworkImage(e));
           }
     );
    return ret.map((nI) => new Image(image: nI)).toList();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: You have to change getCarouselWidget into a list of Images. Do you want me to do the conversion? I do not have access so I will write code based on the docs

Comment: Sure. But if you return a list of images then in the widget, you will have to have an itembuilder that builds each image right?

Comment: It seems like carousel does it for you.

Comment: Okay. Then I will appreciate if you can show me how to return a list of images.

Comment: QuerySnapshot is a list of documents.

[ DocumentSnapshot, DocumentSnapshot, DocumentSnapshot]

Comment: So I have actually looped through my snapshot data in an item builder but I am gettnig a cast error. Can you help me resolve it.

Comment: Does your firebase provide an url to the image?

Comment: Yes it does. I copied the "download url" from firebase and then created the document and pasted the urls.

Comment: I assume firebase provides you an url instead of the actual image. Next time, please clearify your question. I do not know firebase provided types so I cannot help you unless it is written in the description.

Comment: I have attached my firestore document which shows the download urls. That's what I want to retrieve.