# How to cast/convert Future<dynamic> into Image?

Tags: dart, flutter, dynamictype

I have function to fetch image like

```
dynamic imgBinary = _repository.fetchImage(productId);
```

And I want to add this into List of Image

```
List<NetworkImage> listImages = new List<NetworkImage>();
```

So like

```
dynamic imgBinary = _repository.fetchImage(productId);
listImages.add(imgBinary);
```

How to cast this?

Comment: @pskink like this? bannerImages.add((imgBinary as NetworkImage)); but still not working says 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'NetworkImage' in type cast

Comment: @pskink it says Instance of 'Future' and for runtimeType it says Future<dynamic>

Comment: `repository.fetchImage(productId).then((i as NetworkImage ){
listImages.add(i);
});`

Comment: read https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures then

Comment: @anmol.majhail thanks it works not exactly as you typed but I did trial and error then voila it works. you might want to put it as an answer so I could accept it? And how to make codes in comment  highlighted?

Comment: also you can use `  , Shift key + Echo Button on Keyword. to wrap you code in comment. like `code`

Comment: @anmol.majhail what is echo button? sorry if it's basic stuff

Comment: it's the First button `on top of tab key` & under esc key on keyboard. wave sign is there on it.

Comment: `Thank you I got it` finally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , So you Can Try `.then` method.

As `_repository.fetchImage(productId);` is Future.

so you can try -

```
List<NetworkImage> listImages = List<NetworkImage>();
    Future<dynamic> imgBinary = _repository.fetchImage(productId);
    imgBinary.then((i){
    listImages.add(i);
    });
```

or

Directly:

```
_repository.fetchImage(productId).then((i){
listImages.add(i);});
```

To get the Value from Future - we can either use :

```
async and await
```

OR
    you can use the `then()` method to register a callback. This callback fires when the Future completes.

For more [info](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#the-future-api)

Comment: It works but how then make a difference? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: or even more directly: `_repository.fetchImage(productId).then(listImages.add);`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: anmol.majhail's answer is better

Your fetchImage method needs to return a future, here's some pseudo code as guidence

```
List<NetworkImage> listImages = new List<NetworkImage>();

Future<void> _fetchAddImageToList(int productId) async {
     //trycatch
    dynamic imgBinary = await _repository.fetchImage(productId);
    listImages.add(imgBinary);
}

Future<NetworkImage> fetchImage(int id) async {
    New NetworkImage img = new NetworkImage();
    //do your fetch work here
    return img;
}
```